# Travelling to Romania on a short stay Schengen visa issued by France?

Tags: schengen, tips-and-tricks, romania

I am Tunisian and I have single entry short stay Schengen visa issued by the French embassy. I live in United Arab Emirates, is it OK to go from United Arab Emirates to Romania and stay there for 5 days and come back to United Arab Emirates? If not, what would I have to do?

Comment: Probably not, what you should do is apply for a Romanian visa, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17855/schengen-visa-holder-issued-by-the-italian-embassy-getting-into-romania-via-fr?rq=1

Comment: Alternately, you could postpone your trip. Romania was supposed to enter the Schengen area on January 1st, it's been postponed for what are quite transparently political reasons (when he announced this, Jose Manuel Barroso also said they were ready) so I hope it might still happen later this year, perhaps after the elections to the European Parliament in May.

Comment: @Dirty-flow Did you read the question before voting to close it?

Comment: @Annoyed copy paste mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Romania is not yet part of Schengen as far as I know, so the Schengen visa is probably irrelevant for Romanian authorities, unless your Tunisian passport allows you visa free travel to Romania I think you need a romanian visa

Comment: It's relevant but only under certain conditions.

Comment: The Schengen visa allows you to visit neighbouring countries not in the Schengen space ?

Comment: Not "visit" per se, but transit (see the link in the comment above). Remember that Romania is not just any neighbouring country. It's a member of the EU, in a process to enter the Schengen area (was supposed to happen in a few weeks from now actually) and already applies most of the rules. +1 to your answer however, I think your conclusion is still the right one.

Comment: so I go from Dubai to Romania and come back to Dubai ?

Comment: @Yousra No, transit would be stopping in Romania on the way between Dubai and Hungary or another Schengen country. But, per the Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs' website, you must have a “coherent itinerary to the country that issued the visa”, which means that if you add a visit to Budapest even if Romania is obviously your main destination (for example you are going to a conference or a wedding there), it could look like you were trying to “cheat” and game the system. I have no idea how strict they are with this in practice.

Comment: Is it ok to go from Dubai to Hungary and then to Romania stay for 5 days and go back to Hungary and then to Dubai.

Comment: @Yousra Well, you can read all the material in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17855/schengen-visa-holder-issued-by-the-italian-embassy-getting-into-romania-via-fr?rq=1 and on the official website and decide for yourself. It *might* be OK but if Romania is your main destination, there is a risk that the Romanian border guards would create problems. I have no idea how big that risk is in practice. If possible, applying for a Romanian visa seems much safer than trying to plan your trip to go around the rules.