# Travelling to Romania for 4 days by Schengen visa issued by Germany?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, romania

I have Schengen visa delivered by Germany, in the German embassy in Morocco, 
I have already Mult entry 90 days, my visa will expire the 11th March 2014. I wanna visit Romania for 4 days. Can I go to Romania by Schengen visa? From Brussels to Bucharest for 4 days, from the 20th February to the 24th February.

Comment: Romania is not part of the Schengen area, even though it is in the EU. So you should check what the visa requirements for your nationality are for Romania.

Comment: In principle, it's not possible. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17855/schengen-visa-holder-issued-by-the-italian-embassy-getting-into-romania-via-fr?rq=1

Comment: This question has already been discussed several times on this site, you might want to check out the page I linked to above and the comments and questions linked from that page to get more information.

Comment: In principle, this is perhaps a very good example on why it's not always helpful to link to old questions, even if the subject has been discussed several times. It's perhaps even a good example on why questions leading to answers with short-term legal validity are not particularly suitable for this kind of forum at all. In this case, Romania will change their visa regime as of February 1st 2014 and waive the visa requirements for holders of some Schengen visas.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnjbo I strongly disagree. Keeping information up to date is of course a problem (but just about any information on this site is transient by nature) but not linking to old questions is not a solution, a new answer should be provided and upvoted there.

Answer (score 4):

Given that

- you will go to Romania after the 1st of February 2014;
- you will go to Romania during the validity of your Schengen Visa;
- you will stay in Romania for less than 90 days;

you don't need a visa to enter Romania.

Source: Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs

=> [Do I need a visa to come to Romania? Conditions of travelling to Romania](http://mae.ro/en/node/2040)

Comment: The text you're linking to is not particularly well written, but is seems to be an additional requirement that the allowed 90 days must not have been "used up" in other Schengen countries for the visa to be valid in Romania: "... the right of stay established as per the Schengen visas, must not have been exhausted." The exception is also only valid for holders of Schengen visas with 2 or multiple entries.

Comment: +1, good to know. Care to provide updated answer to previous questions about this topic?

Comment: Good Idea.  Done.